# Converting unordered list to select... but with a twist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I'm converting an unordered list of items into a select menu of options.

The HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-container converted">
    <button class="button__black __small" data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false">Artist <img src="{site_url}/do-not-enter-or-modify-or-erase/site-theme/img/dropdown-arrow.png" alt="Dropdown" /></button>
    <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown mega book-filter-dropdown category-dropdown" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a class="active" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
// Create the dropdown base
$("<select />").appendTo(".converted");

//Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
  "selected": "selected",
  "value"   : "catalog/products",
  "text"    : "All Artists"
}).appendTo(".converted select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$(".converted a").each(function() {
  var el = $(this);
  $("<option />", {
    "value"   : el.attr("href"),
    "text"    : el.text()
  }).appendTo(".converted select");
});

$(".converted select").change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
});
```

I'd like the list item with a class of "active" to be presented in the select dropdown as an option with "selected=selected".

How do I do that?

Comment: Pls create a fiddle.

Comment: I see no `a` element in your code. Where are they? You mean `li`? Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/03kh3nuL/)

Comment: `"selected" : el.hasClass("active"),` ...so where's the "twist"?

Answer (score 1):

You should have the attr `selected=true|false`. Either look at [$.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) as in `el.prop('selected', true|false)` or pass in the value when creating the element:

```
$("<option />", {
    "value"   : el.attr("href"),
    "text"    : el.text(),
    "selected": el.hasClass("active")
}).appendTo(".converted select");
```

Comment: The problem is that there is no `a` element. I think OP refers to `li`, but he didn't clarify it.

Comment: Yes, that is one issue, but not the question he asked.

Comment: My mistake. I corrected the code, adding the a element.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a check for the `active` class in the `.each()` part. Also, I would suggest removing the `.appendTo()` function from the .`each()` because an append to the DOM is quite an expensive operation, so what you need to do instead is to create an array of elements in the `.each()` and later append that array in one go.

Consider having something like this:

```
var lis = $('#drop1').children('li'),
    target = $('.target'),
    options = [],
    $element;

lis.each(function(index, element){
    $element = $(element);

    options.push($("<option />", { "value" : $element.attr("href"), "text" : $element.text(), "selected": $element.hasClass('active') }));
});

target.append(options)
```

This can be seen online here: http://jsfiddle.net/3n34g90q/